# HTTP 404 status after .war file deployment on heroku

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, deployment, war

I develop an app in JEE with Apache Tomcat 9.0.
I created a .war file using `java -cvf app-name.war *`.
I do have a problem with .war file deployment on heroku:

[image: screenshot]

Moreover, I am a new user here, if you give me hints about posting here I will be really happy.

Comment: Welcome here. Can you elaborate what have you done to debug this? Because there could be many different reason for a 404. For example, does the war file run fine locally?

Comment: @HarryQ I run this program in IDE and it did open succesfully. I also tried to add <welcome-file-list> in web.xml file but unfortunately it didn't work. Could you please tell me how can I run .war file locally?

Comment: Assuming you are using command line. You can download the Tomcat package from their website, unzip it, navigate to ./bin folder, type ```./catalina.sh start```, then copy your .war file into the ```webapps``` folder. Tomcat should automatically load and runit. You can visit your webapp at  ```http://localhost:8080/YOUR_WAR_FILENAME```

Comment: @HarryQ I've managed to solve the problem - thank you for you help!
 I did reorganize files in app's directory before creating a .war file and then after a successful local deployment it also worked on Heroku